# Проверка синтаксиса VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio

Здравствуйте.

В VS 2013 Ultimate стала очень долго думать проверка синтаксиса. Так, например, стоит мне опечататься и написать `doublr` вместо `double`, как она тут же подчеркивает ошибку, при исправлении подчеркивание красным висит еще секунд 10, и при наведении на уже правильный `double` он пишет **this declaration has no storage class or type specifier**.

Казалось бы ничего, и так понятно, что все правильно, но в случае когда подчеркивается более серьезная ошибка, когда так навскидку и не скажешь, верно ты ее исправил или нет, то надоедает сидеть и ждать, когда оно там сообразит, верно я исправил или нет.

Раньше такого не наблюдал, может, кто знает, как оптимизировать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

visual studio тюнингу не поддается, скорей всего, это операционная система подвисает.

Comment: Спасибо, буду иметь ввиду)